# Does anyone know the Windows Azure bandwidth is calculated by bit or byte?

Tags: azure

Data transfers measured in GB = GigaBit or GigaByte?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like it's calculated with GigaByte ( http://www.itstrategists.com/Microsoft-Azure.aspx and http://www.pcworld.com/article/168388/microsoft_reveals_windows_azure_pricing_availability.html ), also it usually is that GB = GigaByte